# JavaScript / mongoose - Loop through an array to create array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

At the moment I have a list of Team ID's which I have stored in the array `teamIds`. I also have a function `findByKey` in my `Team` mongoose schema which finds a Team based on its key. As you can see from the code I have to put each new `Team.findByKey` inside the previous one, if I put it outside of the previous findByKey it doesn't function correctly.

I'm having problems putting the `Team.findByKey` methods into some sort of for loop which can loop through the array `teamIds` and for each `Team` in the array. I am developing the function to create a new tournament, the idea is that you pass an array of teamIds to here, and it loops through each ID, searching for that Team and adding it to a `teamsList` array in order to create the tournament.

I need to put the last bit of code to create the array of `Team` objects into the last `Team.findByKey` method which is my problem. How would I fix this so that I can pass it `n` amount of teams and find each team and store it as an array of `Teams`?

This is my code:

```
  app.get('/tournament', function(req, res){
    function genMatches(nTeams) {
      var matchArray = [];
      while (nTeams > 1) {
          nTeams = nTeams >> 1;
          var matches = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < nTeams; ++i) {
              matches.push([]);
          }
          matchArray.push(matches);
      }
      return matchArray;
    }

    var teamIds = [
      1364472344972,
      1363173222886,
      1363007586845,
      1363007557484
    ]

    var tournamentName = 'My Tournament';

    Team.findByKey(teamIds[0], function(err, team1) {
        if(err) {
          util.log("Error occured");
        }
        if(!team1) { 
          util.log("The team does not exist");
        }
        Team.findByKey(teamIds[1], function(err, team2) {
          if(err) {
            return util.log("Error occured");
          }
          if(!team2) { 
            return util.log("The team does not exist");
          }
          Team.findByKey(teamIds[2], function(err, team3) {
            if(err) {
              return util.log("Error occured");
            }
            if(!team3) { 
              return util.log("The team does not exist");
            }
            Team.findByKey(teamIds[3], function(err, team4) {
              if(err) {
                return util.log("Error occured");
              }
              if(!team4) { 
                return util.log("The team does not exist");
              }
              var teamList = [
                team1._id,
                team2._id,
                team3._id,
                team4._id
                ];

              var numRounds = Math.log(teamList.length)/Math.log(2);

              var matches = genMatches(teamList.length);
              for(var i = 0; i < matches[0].length; i++){
                matches[0][i] = [ teamList[i+i], teamList[i+(i+1)] ]
              }

              var tournament = new Tournament({
                name: tournamentName,
                teams: teamList,
                rounds: numRounds,
                matches: matches
              });

              res.send(tournament);

            });
          });
        });
      });
  });
```

Team schema:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var validatePresenceOf = function(value){
  return value && value.length; 
};

var toLower = function(string){
  return string.toLowerCase();
};

var getId = function(){
  return new Date().getTime();
};

/**
  * The Team schema. we will use timestamp as the unique key for each team
  */
var Team = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'name' : { type : String,
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Team name is required'],
              index : { unique : true }
            }
});

/**
  * Get complete team details for all the teams
  */
Team.statics.getAll = function(cb){
  var query = this.find({});
  query.sort({key : -1});
  return query.exec(cb);
};

Team.statics.findByKey = function(key, cb){
  return this.find({'key' : key}, cb);
};

Team.statics.findByName = function(name, cb) {
  return this.find({'name' : name}, cb);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', Team);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in) operator to look up your four teams in one query:

```
Team.find({key: {$in: teamIds}}, function (err, teams) {
  ...
});
```

If for some reason you need to call `findByKey` multiple times instead of collapsing it all into a single `$in`, look at using the `async` library's [`each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) method to do that more cleanly.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the code for the `Team` Schema, could you see if that helps at all? I'm not too keen on using another library as I don't think I will be able to get my head around it if there is a way to do it like this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @germainelol i updated my answer to use the actual `key` field name.

Comment: Thanks, this works and I can output an array of Teams to the page, my only issue is that the `teams` array created by this function is only usable inside this function. How would I make it so I am creating an array of `Teams` that I can use throughout this `/tournament` method in order to use it later on?

Comment: @germainelol You would need to use a callback function to make the Team array available to code outside of the `find` callback.

Comment: sorry to be a pain, are you about to show an example of that, I'm just about getting to grips with JavaScript add it is unfortunately

Comment: @germainelol It would be better to ask that as a separate question.  But do some searches first as there are many existing questions about the topic.